# AWS S3 CLI mv vs sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the difference between:

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket2/ 

aws s3 mv s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket2/ --recursive
```

When would I use which?

If we move new docs to AWS what is now on s3?

Answer (score 20):

`aws s3 sync` copies any files that have changed on the source location, it does NOT delete anything on the target location.

`aws s3 sync --delete` copies files changed in the source location, and DELETES files from the target location that have been removed from source.

`aws s3 cp` copies all files from source to target, regardless of them changing in the source, does not delete anything on the target.

`aws s3 mv` moves changed files from source to target, and DELETES the respective files in the source location.

For more information, AWS has documentation on the [High Level Use of the S3 CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html), and the more detailed [CLI Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/) documentation.